# Pushing a branch to a remote server fails

Tags: macos, git, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a project which uses Git on a remote server. I installed [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) for Mac to manage it. I also have a .ssh folder with the private in the root directory where I keep all my projects and the public key is in the server.

I was able to clone the project successfully and even commit+push it back with no problem. Then I ceated a branch in my local repo, added a new file and tried commit+push it. It was committed but the pushing failed with the following error message.

```
Pushing to git@gitserver:gitbtest

ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitserver: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Is there a way to set SSH keys in SourceTree for Mac? I can't seem to find any option to do so.

Any help to resolve this would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you change anything between the time you successfully pushed from your repo/master and the time you are pushing from your branch?

Comment: After testing pushing from the master, I just created a branch, added a new file to it and tried pushing it to the server. That's when this problem occurred.

Comment: do you have a `$HOME/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: No, I only have these 3 files in the .ssh folder. id_rsa, id_rsa.pub, known_hosts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An url like `git@gitserver:gitbtest` can only work if one have an ssh config file in order to resolve the name `gitserver`:

```
$HOME/.ssh/config

Host gitserver
   Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx # IP or full name for gitserver
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Actually, with such a file, you don't even have to specify the user:

```
git remote set-url origin gitserver:gitbtest
```

(You can see an example of that `~/.ssh/config` file used in "[git public key for more repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24135308/6309)")