# How to clone a git private repo under a different registered user?

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub handle that I've used for years, however, after joining a new company, they required that I register a new GitHub account under the company email address. Now I can't clone the private repo because the user.name is set as my normal GitHub handle.

I read [on this page](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-username-in-git) that I can add my username before the URL like `git clone https://usernamenew@github.com/companyname/repo-name.git`.

However, I get the error

```
Cloning into 'repo-name'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://usernamenew@github.com/companyname/repo-name.git/' not found
```

How do I clone the company's repo using a different user name?

Comment: Are you using your GitHub password or a token of some sort?

Comment: password. not token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your example output, git is not asking you for a password. It looks like:

- Your credentials are cached
- The credentials are for your personal account, not your new company account

You have correctly added your new username to the URL. But by default, git only cares about the host when applying cached credentials.

You can use the `useHttpPath` option of `gitcredentials` to tell git to consider the URL path, as well. This will allow you to use different accounts with different repositories.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-useHttpPath

> **useHttpPath**
>
> By default, Git does not consider the "path" component of an http URL to be worth matching via external helpers. This means that a credential stored for https://example.com/foo.git will also be used for https://example.com/bar.git. If you do want to distinguish these cases, set this option to true.

Configure this by running the following command:

```
git config --global credential.https://github.com.useHttpPath true
```

Answer (score 1):

The config `user.name` has nothing to do with authentication.

Do check you [`git config credential.helper`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) setting.
If set, that means your credentials might be cached: you would need to remove them or, better, use an SSH URL (one where you can set a [different private key for different URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23751734/6309))

If this is not a cached issue, simply check that `usernamenew` does have access to `github.com/companyname/repo-name.git`.

Comment: `git config credential.helper` returns nothing

Comment: @xiaodai Then check if /usernamenew has actually access to github.com/companyname/repo-name.git