# How import repository in gitlab from a ssh git repository url?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I want to import a project in gitlab with ssh://

I have on the same network :

- a gitlab installed on a raspebrry
- a git server on a synology

My git server is only available via ssh://*****@mysynology:/the/repository/path/myproject.git

I tried with ssh key authentication without password but I don't know the user used by gitlab to do the git clone...

I have this message in gitlab:

```
Error importing repository ssh://*****@mysynology/the/repository/path/myproject.git into root/myproject - Cloning into bare repository '[REPOS PATH]/root/myproject.git'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try first to SSH to `*****@mysynology`, and make sure `/the/repository/path/myproject.git` is accessible.

Then clone on your local PC that repo, using the SSH URL.

Finally, push back to your GitLab.

> I don't know the user used by gitlab to do the git clone...

No need: create a new empty GitLab repository (to receive your push).
And the GItLab page for that new repository will show you the SSH user you should include in your SSH URL (usually '`git`')

Comment: Ok thanks, but I want to keep my repo on my synology and do all my push/pull on my synology, is it possible ?

Comment: @jeremy.romano Yes, my answer was talking about your GitLab, the one on your synology.

Comment: Sorry but my gitlab is on a raspberry, only my git server is on my synology

Comment: @jeremy.romano OK then: your GitLab on raspberry: as long as you have a valid SSH key registered on it, you can configure your local SSH to use that key when pushing to your GitLab (with a .ssh/config file, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23751734/6309)