# Can't switch github username in terminal

Tags: git, github, terminal

I believe the answer was discussed here, but I'm having trouble following it:

[Having Trouble Switching Github accounts on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548158/having-trouble-switching-github-accounts-on-terminal)

I need very detailed instructions as to what directory to access from terminal, then a list of commands to enter. The conceptual answer is meaningless to me at my level of experience.

Comment: This might help: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574

Comment: Everything seemed to work, I even looked up how to delete all previous keys then went through these steps again. But it's still attached to my old username.