# Github - permission denied to old account

Tags: linux, git, shell, github, ssh

Problem faced:
I cannot `git push` to my repo, error message:

```
remote: Permission to fishercoder1534/Leetcode.git denied to MY_OLD_GITHUB_ACCOUNT
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/fishercoder1534/Leetcode.git/': 
The requested URL returned error: 403`
```

Research I have done:

1. looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548158/having-trouble-switching-github-accounts-on-terminal), I have all these correctly pointing to my new github account:
   `git config --global user.name "NewAccountFirstname NewAccountLastname"
   git config --global user.email "my_new_github_account_email@gmail.com"`
2. I have deleted my old ssh keys, generated new ssh keys, placed them under ~/.ssh/, also add them into my new Github account.
3. I have created a ~/.ssh/config file with the following contents as suggested by the above post:
   `Host github.com
       User           git
       IdentityFile   ~/.ssh/id_rsa # wherever your "new" key lives
       IdentitiesOnly yes`
4. I have run `$ssh -vT git@github.com` which all shows my new Github account info. `Hi fishercoder1534! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`
5. I have run `$ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -vT git@github.com`, it's also showing my new Github info, with `Hi fishercoder1534! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

What's next option to try/help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An https url (https://github.com/fishercoder1534/Leetcode.git) means that every settings you have done for *ssh* doesn't matter.
And `user.name`/`user.email` have nothing to do with a Git repo server authentication.

Check if you have cached your https `github.com` credentials in a credential manager with [`git credential.helper`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials):

```
git config credential.helper
```

That would explain why your old account keeps being used.
For `osxkeychain`, [you can update your account](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/)

Or, of course, you can switch to an ssh url:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:fishercoder1534/Leetcode.git
```

Comment: That's right: `git config credential.helper`, it returns me `osxkeychain`

Comment: @fishercoder1534 I have added a link for you to update your https credentials.

Comment: @fishercoder1534 no problem: remember, https and ssh are two different protocols: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-HTTP-Protocols vs. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol