# Multiple Github accounts on the same computer using the Windows application

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I'm using the Github applications for Windows for 2 accounts.
One is my personal and the other one is a professional account.

The problem is that everytime I logout and login (depending on which project I'm working on) Github sends me an email that a new ssh key pair has been generated for this computer.

I tried to unsubscribe from these mails or even setup a fixed multiple key pair but to no avail.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** intended by GitHub to have several User-Accounts for different needs. Ususally you have **only one User-Account** and use the collaborative-features on repositories to work together.

In a professional context you'd use GitHub's [organizations](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations) to create teams for the specific repositories - where every team-member uses its one and only GH-account.

However, to use different GitHub-accounts you may try to use the Git CLI as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer) or a different Git GUI ([Sourcetree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/) seems to provide a kind of multiple account-management).