# Git global config user depends on system account?

Tags: git, git-config

Centos 6, Git 2.0.4

Setting up git on a server for another developer, as system root I did:

```
root@server $ git config --global user.name "My Dev Guy"
root@server $ su mydevguy
mydevguy@server $ git config --list
```

No user was set! So, as system user "mydevguy" I did:

```
mydevguy@server $ git config --global user.name "Some Other Guy"
mydevguy@server $ git config --list
```

Shows "Some Other Guy" as the user name, as expected. So I exit back to system root user and see what's there.

```
mydevguy@server $ exit
root@server $ git config --list
```

And it still shows "My Dev Guy" there.

I thought these were global git settings, but it seems to be possible to configure git users per system users. Is that so? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: I think you may be looking for `git config --system`?

Comment: I wasn't really "looking" for anything, but you have helped me find it. This is awesome because everything else I found seemed to say you couldn't have more than one git user working on the same machine, which seemed absurd. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer

Comment: check the options [--global, --system, and --local](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) in the manpage. These options clearly specify which configuration files are affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When reading, the values are read from the system, global and repository local configuration files by default, and options ***--system, --global, --local and --file <filename>*** can be used to tell the command to read from only that location

The different locations mean;

> --local  Use the repository .git/config file (per repository)
>   --global Use the global ~/.gitconfig file (per user)
>   --system Use the system-wide $(prefix)/etc/gitconfig (per system)

`--local` is the default for writing, for reading the default is to read all the files.

[Reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).