# How can I configure GitLab and GitHub ssh key on my PC

Tags: linux, git, github, gitlab

I have my personal GitHub account and I have GitLab account for work. I am using `id_ed25519` for GitHub and it works perfectly. As I read in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40549348/is-it-possible-to-use-github-and-gitlab-on-one-machine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56287059/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-config-file-for-beginners), I should be able to create two different key and use for different accounts. Therefore, I created `id_rsa` for GitLab and added to my GitLab account but all the time I am having below error.

```
Cloning into 'product'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gitlab.company.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My config file is located on `~/.ssh/config` and as shown as below

```
Host github
HostName github.com 
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Host gitlab.company.com
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Also, you can see which files contain `.ssh` folder

```bash
> ls -1
config
id_ed25519
id_ed25519.pub
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
known_hosts
known_hosts.old
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: That error indicates that `gitlab.company.com` isn't reachable (probably, isn't resolving). Can you `telnet gitlab.company.com 22`, or `dig gitlab.company.com +short`? Do you need to add a `Hostname` below that `Host` with an IP address or something else?

Comment: How are you cloning your gitlab repo?

Comment: adding to @ZacAnger's comment : a generic way to debug ssh issues is : `ssh -v gitlab.company.com` -- but as said in that other comment: it looks like a name resolving issue

Comment: @ZacAnger telnet output is `telnet: could not resolve gitlab.company.com/22: Name or service not known`. dig doesn't have any output. I can access to GitLab with this link `https://10.190.16.13/`. when I run VPN

Comment: @LeGEC but `config` file should handle that. Isn't it? Or how can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you are trying to access `10.190.16.13`. So, you need to add that link inside `/etc/hosts` file.

```
10.190.16.13    gitlab.company.com
```

Then it should be good to go

Answer (score -2):

how are you? I noticed that you provided some links as a reference for the steps you followed to create the SSH key. From those links, it seems like you are using Windows, am I right? In the post you shared, it mentions manually creating the config file. However, have you tried generating the key using the `ssh-keygen` command, which is available on most operating systems? It might be worth giving it a try. Check this link from GitHub:
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent