# How to switch my credentials on a Gitlab repo from the console?

Tags: git, terminal, gitlab

The thing is that I already set up my username and password.
But now I am going to work on a special repository where I have to set different credentials and I need to do it from the console.

All I see on the internet is how to set your name and email.
But, in which part the console will ask me for my username and password?

Obviously when I try to clone that repo, the console throws an error saying that I don't have permissions. That's why I need to put my old credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mainly two ways to do that, SSH and HTTPS. [Both methods are covered by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer). Based on your information, I think the HTTPS way is what you are looking for.