# PhpStorm. Two GitHub projects handled with different GitHub accounts

Tags: git, github, phpstorm, project-management, account

I have 2 different GitHub projects and I want to handle them separately. Each project with different GitHub account but it seems impossible.

After get into `Settings - Version Control - Github`, there is only one place to put user and password (or token) and it seems is shared for all PhpStorm projects. If I change to the other project it keeps the settings and if after that I update the credentials after changing to the first project again the credentials I put lately are still set.

Is possible to handle in the way I want?

Comment: Accordingly to JetBrains Issue Tracker -- it's not really really possible: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82222 **P.S.** Try specifying username in URL -- maybe it will work that way (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27407168/783119)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around the PHPStorm settings for git credentials at the git level if you update your repositories to reference their remotes via `ssh` rather than `https`.

You can update local repositories to another remote with the [`git remote set-url`](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) command.

Once you've switched to using ssh key authentication rather than https user/password auth, if you want to use multiple keys (one for each account) you can follow this guide [which details how to configure git to use different private keys for different repositories](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996).