# git push origin master denied to user X where x is NOT the user in the local git config

Tags: windows, git, github, version-control

Prefacing this with **I am very new to git and github**.
I set up a repo on github, as user zzz, and it is correctly listed in my local (repo-specific) git config file, which has entries like the following when I do `'git config --local --list'`:

```
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/zzz/myrepo.git
user.name=zzz
user.email=yyy@example.com
```

But when I do do `git push origin master`, it get **403 denied to user 'xxx'**... a user which corresponds to a completely separate github account. How do I fix this? And why is it picking up user 'xxx' when that is not the user i carefully specified in the local config file? I am on windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git store credentials in Windows, clear them referring below image:

[image]

Run your `git push` command, it will prompt you to enter credentials again.

Image Courtesy - [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git#42557915)

Comment: That worked!!! So but what if I want to use git as 2 different users on the same machine? For some repos I want to be user Z, for others I want to be user X. I will have clear my windows credentials each time? Just curious...

Comment: This might help you in that case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer