# ! [remote rejected] master -> master (permission denied) error: failed to push some refs to https://github.com/username/gitname.git

Tags: git, github

I have created a repository in my laptop, added a new `index.html` file to that repository , staged, commited, then I created a repository on github account. After that I pushed a repo to github. It was done successfully.

Then, I forked that repository with my other github account, cloned it to another directory in my laptop, added new changes, then I wanted to push this  forked new repository which located in my laptop to this second github account. But console shows me an error like this:

> Counting objects: 3, done.
>
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
>
> Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
>
> Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 310 bytes | 155.00 KiB/s, done.
>
> Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
>
> To https://github.com/username/repo.git
>
> ! [remote rejected] master -> master (permission denied)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/repo.git'

I would like to push repository to github as [in this tutorial](https://youtu.be/HbSjyU2vf6Y?t=4m23s)

I have searched about this error, and I did 
`git pull --rebase` and even `git push -
 f https://github.com/account_name/repo.git`
but these commands did not help to solve this error.

How can I push the repository to github?

P.S. Written github account name is conditional.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Comment: I think no, I would like to do like this: 
[link](https://youtu.be/HbSjyU2vf6Y?t=4m23s) @phd

Comment: @nihat, do you have write access to the repository?

Comment: I have checked this situation in other laptop. When I try to push forked repository to second account, it was done with successfully. I think, the problem was that I was attempting to access two account in a laptop.