# Change the Github account I'm using in Git terminal?

Tags: git, github

Dumb question. So I'm "logged in" under one of my GitHub accounts in Git Bash and I need to push to a repo under a different account of mine. Best way to change accounts in Git Bash? Or, for the hell of it, any way I can just give access to my other account? Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Are you on iOS? Most likely it is stored in your OS's keychain, remove it from there and then it will again ask for creds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Answer (score 0):

You can view what account you have using:

```
git config -l
```

Then you can change the credentials and push, then change the credentials again.

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Probably need to see the multiple account question other user listed but this is a quick way to go around it.

Comment: `user.name`/`user.email` have nothing with authentication. They're only used for commits.