# Is it possible to have two Git profiles under one Windows user?

Tags: windows, git

I am using git bash to for Git credentials on my Windows machine. Since the credentials are added and used automatically, is there a way to add more than one Git profile/credential in Git for Windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a config per repo.

For your user info it would be `user.name` and `user.email` with no `--gobal` issued from within the repo folder.

```
git config user.name "<name>"
git config user.email "<email>"
```