# Gitlab console frozen when entering password

Tags: git, authentication, gitlab, passwords

I am trying to create a project on GitLab. I have up to the point of committing a new project with `git cli` but it freezes (no input goes in). The command I used was `git push -u origin master`, it asks me a question and does not commit.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiydP.png)

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you're seeing as a code block?

Comment: after entering *username* and *password* the cursor isn‘t showable? And it displayed no error message like "wrong password" or "user doesn‘t exist" or so...?

Answer (score 1):

When it prompts you for the password, nothing will update on the window, but it is recording your input. Type your answer and hit enter.

I had this issue when using an older version of git with a repo that had LFS enabled. After entering my password, it would just freeze.
Make sure you have the latest version of git installed and try `git push -v -u origin master` to get verbose output and see if it's just a large push.

Comment: I had to run my shell as admin in order for the command to work and to install the binaries.

Comment: Now,  I get an new error:
λ git push -u origin master
remote: `HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/username/projectname.git/'`

Comment: Your password is wrong. Do you have caps lock on? If you are able to log in with the same password on their website, try disabling 2 Factor Authentication. If it works, you can set up a personal access token. You can follow Lucas's advice on this link: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/-/issues/980

Comment: It is not my password ,I have mutiple git account set up ,i have to reconfigure how do i setup my pc for two git account and make the final commit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer scroll down to Greg's answer about the remote URL

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively ,I used gitkraken (a software solution) to setup my accounts.I configured each git user and it worked with no collsions.