# How to remove Git (windows) completely? or Relogin Git Windows

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-bash

I was logged in with my work GitHub ID earlier this morning and then I wanted to change back to my personal GitHub account in GIT(Windows). So I removed my work GitHub ID credentials from Windows Credential Manager and then when I tried git push for a new repository it asked to log in and I logged in using my personal GitHub Account. but its still showing my `git config user.name` as 'my work Account Name' and when I try to see the credentials in Windows Credential Manager it says `PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN`

PS - Please tell if theres any way to uninstalling Git completely from windows and then reinstalling to log in with my Personal ID. Because now when I try to uninstall and then reinstall it still showing me previous username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is configure your *SSH setup* with **multiple SSH** keypairs.

If you're working with multiple repositories using different accounts, you need to make sure that your individual repositories have the user settings overridden accordingly:

Setting *username*, *email* and GitHub token – Overriding settings for individual repos.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your_email@your_domain.com"
```

[Look at this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

And this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) explain your problem really well.

To remove *git* on your computer delete the `.git` folder in the respective directory.