# Set up git credential helper store for different folder

Tags: git, git-config

I have two repositories:

**~/.gitconfig**

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/.repoA"]
    path = .gitconfig-repoA
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Documents/.repoB"]
    path = .gitconfig-repoB
```

And then, to avoid repeating tokens each time I have to push/pull something, I write this file

**.gitconfig-repoA**

```
[user]
    email = emailA@smtp.com
    name = myName
[credential]
    helper = store
```

**.gitconfig-repoB**

```
[user]
    email = emailB@smtp.com
    name = myName
[credential]
    helper = store
```

But I have to type my token each time yet... How should I do to avoid that?

Comment: If you're including `.gitconfig-repoA` why are you storing the configuration data in `.repoA`? Perhaps you should store it in `.gitconfig-repoA`, or include `.repoA`.

Comment: Sorry I typed too fast. I just updated.

Comment: OK - well, if it's using the `store` stuff it should store the credential. That should stick around—though if this is for a single site (e.g., for GitHub) you will need to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62730990/save-multiple-password-accounts-for-git here. (I use ssh myself and hence don't use this approach at all.)