# How can i change github credentials on demand?

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-credential-manager

I have one github account with which i am logged in on microsft edge browser. The other one is on chrome.
Mainly i use the one from microsoft edge, and on first commit github ask again for user name and password when i tried to push, i logged in successfull and after that i always used that account and i pushed without problems.

Now i need to push something on the other account on chrome. But i am still somehow 'logged' on my pc as the github account that i use on microsoft edge.

And when i try to push on ther other account ( of course i added first remote origin of repo from that account ) i get

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to xxxx.git denied to some-user-name.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/project-name.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

how can i solve this ?

Comment: Have you try to use ssh instead of https ?
Why not just use one user and give access to his user to the several repository ?

Comment: To try ssh ? to add remote origin with ssh ?

Comment: yeap, use ssh for one, and https for the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple github accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)