# Does GitHub allowed 2 accounts for 1 user with two different email address

Tags: github, github-pages

I have to use two GitHub account to manage my repo, (personal and professional), So My question is Can I use two GitHub Account with two different emails on a single computer, I don't want to use SSH. Please help.

Comment: You can use an account and can customize the routing of the emails under `Settings > Notifications > Custom routing`. You can also configure git which mail address to use when committing new code. What is the reason why you need two accounts? Otherwise, it should be easy to use two accounts.

Comment: You can also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27407168/10951752).

Comment: I need this because I have many repos in my account which consists of my personal projects and clients project and I want to separate them with individual accounts. BTW Thanks a lot.