# Can't access non default account

Tags: git, github

On my computer I am trying to work with two different git accounts. A default one for work, and a private one for play.

In my user folder (MacOS) the default user is defined.

```
// .gitconfig
[user]
    name = workUserName
    email = work@email.com
```

In the project .git folder

```
// .git 
[user]
    name = privateUserName
    email = private@email.com
```

But when I'm in the project folder and I try to push I get the following failure message:

```
remote: Permission to privatUserName/project.git denied to workUserName.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/privateUserName/project.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What is happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: That name and email address is only used when constructing commits. Authenticating to the remote is a different part of git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3860112/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+multiple+accounts

Answer (score 0):

The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name) mentions that `user.name` should be “your personal name, generally a form using a given name and family name.” It also notes that “[t]his configuration doesn’t have any effect on authenticating to remote services.”

If you want to configure multiple accounts, the FAQ documents how to do that both [for HTTPS](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-http) and [for SSH](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-ssh).