# Visual Studio code doesn't ask for Git credentials for a specific project

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, credentials

I know the question may sounds weird but please hear me out, I am so confused. hope there are someone here can save me (I'm beginner to git..)

I am working on vs code, Win10, gitlab.
I have 2 project-folders in the folder, both project cloned from gitlab:

`C:\Users\Sam\Documents\gitlab\project_a` and `C:\Users\Sam\Documents\gitlab\project_b`

---

when I open a particular project (**project_a**) on vs code, I can git pull/push with a box open-up for username & pw. [enter_username_pw]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKZOp.png

---

but when I open ANY OTHER projects directly, it said access denied. workflow as below:

- open vs code
- open folder **project b**
- access denied as below --

```
PS C:\Users\Sam\Documents\gitlab\project_b> git pull
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/project/project_b.git/'
```

---

What really confused me is when I open the particular project again on vs code (project a),
then cd back to project b, I will be able to pull/push with the box pop-up for username and pw again. workflow as below:

- open vs code of project b
- git pull/push
- access denied, without box for typing username / pw
- closed vs code of project b
- open vs code of project a
- in the workspace of project a, open terminal
- cd into project b
- git pull/push
- success with the box pop-up

feels like there is sth wrongly set with workspace and git credential but i dont have a clue... Could someone have any hint what's happening? Thank yo very much for any help...

Comment: Is `projectb` a subfolder in `projecta`? Is there any difference between `git config --local -l` when executed in the root folders of `projecta` and `projectb`?

Comment: Adding usernames in the urls (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54835151/10710682) may fix it.