# How do I use two github accounts in same computer?

Tags: github

OS : Mac

I use my work github account and also my personal account. I need to switch between them and work on the company project as well as my mini-project (which needs to be pushed to my personal account).
How do I do that ? I use Vscode as editor.

I looked on to other related question and solution but everything seems too mixed up. And also SSH methods out there seems super confusing. Can I switch to my personal account and then back to my work repo without messing up my work repo (where lot other people work on).
How do I do this as easily ?

This link dint help me much : [Multiple GitHub accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Answer (score -3):

can't you log out and then sign into your other account?