# Multiple git accounts on same machine

Tags: git, github

I have a folder structure thus on my machine:

```
c:/officialGit/
    .git/
```

The output of running `git config --list` in `c:/officialGit/` command line is:

```
user.email=official_email_id@gmail.com
user.name=official_user_name
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/official_user_name/officialGit.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Within the above folder, I created a subfolder

```
c:/officialGit/forPersonalPractice/
```

The idea of this subfolder is that I want to practice git commands using a different email id and repository (local and remote) that does not in any way corrupt/interfere with the `officialGit` repository (local and remote) above and vice versa.

Following answer specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67551599/492307), I navigated to subfolder `/forPersonalPractice/` and issued `git init`

Then, I issued:

```
git config user.name Personal_Practice_UserName
git config user.email Personal_Practice@email.com
```

From the same subfolder, to verify if things are correctly set up, I issued `git config --list`. I obtain:

```
user.email=official_email_id@gmail.com
user.name=official_user_name
...
user.name=Personal_Practice_UserName
user.email=Personal_Practice@email.com
```

That is, `user.name` and `user.email` seem to have multiple entries.

I created a private online repository whose link is `https://github.com/Personal_Practice_UserName/PersonalProject.git`

When I now issue `git clone https://github.com/Personal_Practice_UserName/PersonalProject.git` from the `/forPersonalPractice/` subfolder, I obtain

```
Cloning into 'PersonalProject'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Personal_Practice_UserName/PersonalProject.git/' not found
```

Is there a missing step or should I follow a completely different setup on this single machine where the `.git/` folder of `/officialGit/` and `/officialGit/forPersonalPractice/` are not hierarchically nested maybe?

---

ETA: Running `git config user.name` in `c:/officialGit/` returns `official_user_name`. Running that in `c:/officialGit/forPersonalPractice/` returns `Personal_Practice_UserName`. Running `git config credential.helper` in both folders returns `manager-core`.

Comment: Just to note, [`user.name` is a personal name, not a username](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#user-name).

Comment: @bk2204 My actual name is the official user name. For this practice, I use an anonymized username on github. That is, for this practice repository, I do not want to reveal my actual name/identity as any part of the settings (local or remote).

Comment: There are multiple entries because they are configured in different levels. Use `git config user.name` to see which name takes effect. You could just make a test commit to see which name and email are used in the current repository.

Comment: The value of `user.name` does  not take part in the authentication. The clone with the http/https url uses your github username and password/token. As it did not ask you to enter them manually, some credential helper could be working. They are cached somewhere. Run `git config credential.helper` to see what it is. If the repository does exist in github, the cached account does not have access to the repository, so it complained the repository was not found.

Comment: @ElpieKay I have updated the OP with the output of commands you suggest. credential.helper in both cases is `manager-core`. Should I manually change this from within `c:/officialGit/forPersonalPractice/` ?

Comment: `manager-core` corresponds to Windows's Credential Manager. My Windows system language is not English, so I'm afraid I cannot give more advises. You can find an entry related to github in Credential Manager and find the username and password stored there.

Comment: @ElpieKay yes, this helped. I was able to go into Window's credential manager and remove the default git credentials there that were corresponding to my official id. Then, when I tried to clone from the personal directory, it explicitly asks for new username and password. Once provided, I was able to go ahead and clone it. Thanks for your help.