# git config --list has two entries for user.name

Tags: git, terminal, credentials

I don't know how I've ended up at this stage but on my Mac, using the terminal, if I enter `git config --list`, I obtain

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
init.defaultbranch=main
user.email=username1@gmail.com
user.name=username1
.
.
.
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
user.name=username2
```

Why are there two user.name entries and how do I remove username2? The source of this problem was trying to set up two GitHub credentials, one for work (username1) and one for personal (username2).

If I try `git config user.name "username1"`, then I get

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
init.defaultbranch=main
user.email=username1@gmail.com
user.name=username1
.
.
.
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
user.name=username1
```

which is better but there's still two entries!

Comment: `--show-origin` option could help understand where the settings come from: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---show-origin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have one name in your global git config (not on my mac, but may be ~/.gitconfig) and another in the repo config.  Personally, I'd just edit whichever of the two config files you want gone using `git config -e` with or without `--global`

Haven't used github recently, but I assume it is like other sites.  For ssh, the authentication name goes in the repo url - user@host/repo.

Comment: Thank you - and as a general question, if I add  a config file within the repo folder, does that take priority over the config file outside the repo folder?

Comment: You don't have to add such a file.  It exists under .git/config (or just config for bare repos) and holds the values for the repo.  Yes, local settings override globals (afaik).

Comment: To be precise / pedantic, local configs override global ones for *most* configuration settings, including `user.name` and `user.email`. There are a few settings where the local ones *add on* to the global ones ... but not these two.

Answer (score 1):

You can unset the name with this command:

```
git config --unset user.name
```

And maybe you can find something to be able to create a working and personal environment

[Multiple GitHub accounts on the same computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)