# Why is git giving me "fatal: remote error: is not a valid repository name" when I push my local create-react-app to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, repository, fatal-error

I push to GitHub frequently, without much headache. I'm OK with navigating git issues mostly. I'm not clear on why I can't add/commit/push my local create-react-app (it is literally the stock app with no changes) to GitHub.

I create the react app, then I create the GitHub repository, and then on my local PC I set the remote using `git remote add origin git@github.com:jcomp-03/codeforsofl.git`. Afterwards I add, commit, and try pushing my changes using `git push -u origin main`. I get the following error:

[image: CLI snapshot of error being received]

If I did not know better, GitHub (i.e. the remote) is interpreting that ___ (blank) is not a valid repository name? I don't know what to make of it. Thoughts, community?

Comment: Did you verify the remote has been set correctly with `git remote -v`?

Comment: I did run that command to verify my remotes were added correctly. No issue there.

Comment: If the error persists, contact GitHub support: they might be mapping an old repository path to a new one (as they normally do with lots of repositories) and somehow your repository got caught up in some mapping table glitch such that it's being remapped to an invalid name, which causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

It happened same with me.
On using: **git remote -v** command,I got this.

```
origin  git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git (push)
```

If it shows same results as this,try using **remote set-url** command. The URLs have been duplicated, possibly due to a copy-and-paste error. Regardless of the reason, you can rectify the situation by utilizing the git remote set-url command as:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/<repository>.git
```

*Replace **< username >** and **< repository >** with yours like:*

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Mark/CalculatorApp.git
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Mark/CalculatorApp.git
```

**Do upvote ;)!**

Comment: I don't understand why but that actually worked for me.
I also had the initial problem that `git remote -v` does show the correct origin but i could not push nor fetch.

Answer (score 1):

I hit this a few times too and ultimately re-made the remote repository to fix it, which worked. I've only encountered this with brand new (on Github's side) repositories while trying to push a repo I'd made on my machine to GH.

Since `git remote -v` returned that fetch and push origins were respectively set correctly, it was the only logical thing to do since re-making the empty remote repo is less effort that reaching out for support.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI.
I did a

> git checkout .

and then

> git pull

That reset it. for me

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the solution for most users, but this solution is for folks that have ***multiple*** GitHub users on their pc. I encountered this same error as the question `fatal: remote error: is not a valid repository name`.

Given you have a git and ssh config setup like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3860139/4739826).
Setup:

---

**.ssh/config**

```
Host second-user
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_second
```

**~/.gitconfig**

```
[user]
    name = First User
    email = fu@example.com
```

**~/some-workdir/.gitconfig**

```
[user]
    name = Second User
    email = su@example.com
```

---

My mistake was trying to use `git@github` instead of the Host.

Wrong way to do it:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:seconduser/some-repo.git
```

Right way to do it:

```
git remote add origin second-user:seconduser/some-repo.git
```