github actions cannot push workflow
In a new Github repo I have added a workflow file.  I can edit that file in the online editor.
But when I clone the repo, change the workflow and then try to push, I am getting:
$ LANG=C git push origin HEAD
Enumerating objects: 9, done.
Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 406 bytes | 406.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To https://github.com/...git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> main (refusing to allow a Personal Access Token to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/myfirstaction.yml` without `workflow` scope)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/...git'

I have created Github repos before and using them frequently from the command line to push, pull, etc. and have never come across this problem.
I created a new Access Token with "workflow" box checked with the github web interface as explained in https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens , and saved the token in
$HOME/.get-credentials but with no avail.
I also found https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26254 which says to run
$ git remote add origin https://<key>@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git

And then it works, but my feel ist that the private key is dislocated in .git/config ?

You're almost certainly still using your previous token by default. Clear your saved git credentials and let Git ask you for a password again, at which point you'll be able to provide the new token.

And search for "clear my git credentials" and your OS if you are not sure how to do that.

I am not sure whether I should remove the tokens that may be used by other repos.

This might help then: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3860112/3216427
