# How can I switch between github accounts locally in the projects?

Tags: git, github

So I have 2 github accounts, 1 for work and 1 for me, currently I've changed my main account to work by deleting keychain access, after this using any git command asks you to enter credentials.

But how to switch between accounts depending on project? I want to have 1 github account in 1 project and 2nd in another.
Using commands like

```
git config user.email "you@example.com"
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.password "your password"
```

Does not do anything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36782014/1559611
This shall help you in resolving the mentioned issue

Comment: Git config doesn’t affect GitHub authentication

Answer (score 2):

As you authenticate with your `ssh`-keys, you should use a different `ssh`-key for each account.
You then need to configure the `ssh`-key used for pushing changes, which then again determines the account to authenticate against `github`.
You can do this, by setting a different `core.sshCommand` for each local repository.

The following example assumes `repo1` is using `~/.ssh/key1` and `repo2` is using `~/.ssh/key2`.
In `repo1`, you set `core.sshCommand` to use `~/.ssh/key1` like this.

```
git config --local core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/key1"
```

In `repo2`, you set `core.sshCommand` to use `~/.ssh/key2` like this.

```
git config --local core.sshCommand "ssh -i ~/.ssh/key2"
```

To configure `core.sshCommand` while cloning a repository, use the following command

```
git clone -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/key1" git@github.com:repo1/repo1.git
```

Note that this must be done for every local copy of the `github`-Repository, and also may not working if not using a `Unix` operating system or the `git bash for windows`.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41947805/11688567)

Answer (score 0):

Below could be the possible solution if I got your question correctly :

- You should use `HTTPS` in this case.
- change remote url to https with

  ```
   git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME@github.com/USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git
  ```
- and you are good to go :)
- To ensure that the commits appear as performed by USERNAME, one can setup the user.name and user.email for this project, too:

  ```
  git config user.name USERNAME

  git config user. Email USERNAME@example.com
  ```
- A note : if you already set your user.name and user.email with the --global flag, just do what I said above to set it locally for just that one repo.

###### Hope it will work :)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3860112/multiple-github-accounts-on-the-same-computer)

Comment: It worked, thanks, only additional part is that you need to generate and use Personal Access Token on Git.

Comment: yes, you need to generate the personal access token :) Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I had to use `git remote set-url origin https://USERNAME@github.com/ORGANISATIONNAME/PROJECTNAME.git`