# Multiple bitbucket accounts

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket account for my 9-5 job and I also have a personal Bitbucket account. My goal is to be able to use both on the same computer. I have installed the latest git on a Windows 7 pc.

So currently everything with my companies Bitbucket account works fine, I can pull/push with no problems. I created a new ssh key using ssh-keygen and assigned a new name in my case "tech". But I am having issues on how to tell a local repo to use the new ssh key I created. I am assuming everytime I try to connect it uses the first ssh key.

I get the error:

$ git push
conq: repository access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I found some advice on the internet but it seems to relate to a linux/git setup, for example I can't find the "config" file on windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You may get this error if you haven't added the key to the key manager (ssh-agent). To do this:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/tech
```

By the way, if you have multiple Bitbucket accounts, you'll need a unique key for each account. You can't reuse keys.

Comment: That fixed my problem, the step is missing from the documentation the bitbucket sit. thanks.

Answer (score 125):

[This blog post](http://dbushell.com/2013/01/27/multiple-accounts-and-ssh-keys/) describes a straightforward way to add multiple ssh keys to a single computer and use one ssh key per a bitbucket account. It is much clearer than the [official bitbucket documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168). To summarize:

First, make sure you have a default account setup through a tutorial like [this one on Github](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

For the second account:

1. Create a new ssh key:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/<your second account name> -C "<you email>"
   ```
2. Add the ssh key:

   ```
   ssh-add ~/.ssh/<key file name>
   ```
3. Use `pbcopy < ~/.ssh/<your second account name>.pub` to copy the public key and add this key to your bitbucket account (in the settings area)

(On Windows you can copy the ssh key using [`ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/<your account name> -c "<your email>" | clip`](https://superuser.com/questions/472598/pbcopy-for-windows) or on [Linux you can follow these instructions.](https://superuser.com/questions/288320/whats-like-osxs-pbcopy-for-linux))

4. Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file. The first sets the default key for bitbucket.org. The second sets your second key to an alias `bitbucket-account2` for bitbucket.org:

   ```
   Host bitbucket.org
     Hostname bitbucket.org
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   Host bitbucket-account2
     Hostname bitbucket.org
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your second account name>
   ```
5. You can now clone projects with your default account the same way as before:

   ```
   git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/project.git
   ```
6. To clone a project with the second identity, replace bitbucket.org with the Host that you specified in the `~/.ssh/config` file (i.e. `bitbucket-account2` above):

   ```
   git clone git@bitbucket-account2:username/project.git
   ```

That's it!

Comment: I had to add the ssh key using the following command : ssh-add ~/.ssh/<key file name>

Comment: As @SamikBandyopadhyay points out, on any system using ssh-agent (e.g. Mac since Leopard) you will also need to add the key to the agent using ssh-add. I found without doing this step, ssh was still using the standard id_rsa for the aliased domain, and even when using the ssh -i parameter to explicitly path to the second identity. Very confusing! ssh-add immediately fixed it.

Comment: There is no pbcopy command on windows, so this instruction is incomplete.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko updated to include Windows and Linux pbcopy equivalents.

Comment: This answer should be marked as a solution - really!

Comment: @SamikBandyopadhyay thanks for the suggestion - added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you only need to generate your pubkey once - since you're already setup with BitBucket, where is your `id_rsa` (or whatever you named yours) file? On our Windows installs, it's under the user's home directory in the hidden folder `.ssh`. You should be able to create a `config` file there.

Answer (score -1):

You should generate public/private key pair only once. Then all hosts which have your public key do allow connections from you if you provide the private key.

Comment: If you have only one public/private key pair, then you cannot access two repositories on bitbucket.  When you try to add your public ssh key to the second one, it will complain that that key has already been added to an account.

Comment: @JonCrowell Sounds weird. I've not used bitbucket, but github allows assign one key to several repos. Several keys have sense for different devices. E.g. one for laptop, another for desktop. If your laptop is stolen, you could revoke its key but continue to use the desktop.

Comment: I don't think this should be the accepted answer since accessing Bitbucket is a requirement in the question.

Comment: @Andrew "You only have to create two identities (keys) if you have two different Bitbucket accounts". It tells if you have two accounts, in the question there are two repositories, not accounts.

Comment: @kan - didn't the question say "I have a Bitbucket account for my 9-5 job and I also have a personal Bitbucket account. My goal is to be able to use both on the same computer."? It sounds to me like he has 2 Bitbucket accounts?

Comment: @Andrew Hm, looks like you are right. However, it is weird why it works for him, probably he has different setup.

Answer (score -1):

You can add your company email in your personal bitbucket account, In bitbucket account manage page:

[image]

You can login your personal email account, and access both personal projects and company projects in single bitbucket account, which is using only one ssh private key.

Comment: Wrong! You get `my@googmail.com is already in use by another user.`