# Multiple Bitbucket SSH accounts on same machine

Tags: windows, git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to get multiple Bitbucket accounts working from the same machine via SSH.

In my .ssh\config file, I have:

```
Host account1.bitbucket.org
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account1

Host account2.bitbucket.org
  Hostname bitbucket.org
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/account2
```

Then I'm changing the remote for the git repo to use the alias:

```
git@account1.bitbucket.org:myUserName/myRepoName.git
git@account2.bitbucket.org:myUserName/myRepoName.git
```

Then in Pageant (in the system tray), I'm adding both my PPK keys.

Unfortunately if I've added both keys to Pageant, only one of the accounts work.

If I only have one key in Pageant at a time, then it'll work for whichever Bitbucket account I added to Pageant.

So it looks like pageant isn't using the correct key if there's more than one key in its list.

Any ideas on why it's doing this?

Comment: Why not using the same ssh key for all accounts?

Comment: I could do at a pinch - but I'd rather use separate keys. From reading online, what I describe above should work. There's probably something silly I'm missing.

Comment: So for each account you have to add the key of course and add all the users as collaborators to the project

Comment: This is how I resolved the issue for MacOS: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71520433/4685823).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by not using Pageant. I'm using Sourcetree as a Git GUI, and in the options, there's a dropdown saying whether to use OpenSSH or Putty/Plink.

Based on the description by Steve Streeting here:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/164479/sourcetree-support-multiple-ssh-keys

It sounds like Pageant doesn't use the .ssh\config configuration anyway.

By changing to OpenSSH, then regenerating the keys using ssh-keygen, and adding the private keys via Sourcetree's "Tools .. Add SSH Keys" menu, this is now working perfectly using different keys across multiple accounts. I just need to alter the remote url of each git repo to use the correct alias in the config file (as described in my initial post).

**Update**:

I've written a blog post about this here:
http://www.danclarke.com/multiple-ssh-keys-for-git/

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/150285/only-the-top-listed-private-key-in-pageant-is-used-offered-by-git-sourcetree-tortoisegit) on Atlassian Answers explains how to use PuTTY and SSH with multiple bitbucket account:

> One way to resolve this is to perform the same configuration in PuTTY
>   too to disambiguate what key to send (and therefore which user to
>   authenticate as).
>
> Start PuTTY (download it from putty.org if you don't have it)
>
> Type 'bitbucket.org' in the host name field
>
> Go to Connection > SSH > Auth in the tree
>
> Specify the key to use for the BB user
>
> Go back to 'Session' in the tree
>
> Type an alias name underneath 'Saved Sessions' (e.g. bb-user1) and
>   Save
>
> Repeat 2-6 for each BB user and save as a different session name
>
> Then in your remote URLs, replace 'bitbucket.org' with the session
>   name (e.g. bb-user1) to disambiguate what SSH key to send first. This
>   is identical to using IdentityFile in OpenSSH.

Finally, you can add the keys in pageant to cache the key passcodes.