# Work and personal bitbucket account in config .ssh

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I have this setup in `.ssh/config`. Every time I do a git push it will says permission deny.

My 1st question is that what exactly is `Host` and `HostName`?

2nd question is that if I change `bitbucket_personal` to `bitbucket.org` and `bitbucket_work` to `bitbucket.org`. `bitbucket_work` (the last one in config) will always work, no permission denied issue. Is it a way to make the following config work?

```
Host bitbucket_personal
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User kenpeter
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host bitbucket_work
  HostName bitbucket.org
  User kenpeter_work
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work
```

Ref: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html

Comment: You should be able to diagnose what's going on, roughly.  What would `ssh -vT git@bitbucket-personal` tell you?  If need be, replace `git` with whatever name you SSH to that server normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My 1st question is that what exactly is Host and HostName?

`Host` and `HostName` are SSH options.

The first one initiates conditional block (as illustrated by the indentation) and is matched against the host that is written on command-line or in the clone URL. It can be also understood as an alias.

The `HostName` is basically overwriting that alias with a real hostname so you are going to end up connecting to the correct server, even if you write `ssh -vT git@bitbucket_personal`.

> 2nd question

Well ...  obviously. You need to adjust the clone/push/pull URLs in the `git` to reflect this. Basically for clonning personal repositories, you will need to replace `bitbucket.org` with `bitbucket_personal` and for work ones accordingly with `bitbucket_work`. For existing repositories, do the same in the `.git/config`, where you can find it on several lines.

Comment: Learn something new

Comment: You can also leave the hostname as-is and just replace the "git" portion of the address:

git@bitbucket.org -> kenpeter@bitbucket.org
git@bitbucket.org -> kenpeter_work@bitbucket.org

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the issue for MacOS and OpenSSH, It could help you: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71520433/4685823).