# SSH multiple BitBucket accounts + 2 step verification recovery

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I used to have one BitBucket account for work (w...@dataflow.be) and enabled 2 step verification with Google Authenticator app. Everything used to work fine.

Then I made a personal Bitbucket account (w...@gmail.com) and also enabled 2 step verification with Google Authenticator app.

Now the problem is I can't log into the first account anymore because I only see the second account in my Google Authenticator app.

Then I tried to get the recovery codes for the first account : "ssh git@bitbucket.org recovery_codes" but it also uses my personal account.

Tried to mess around some more with SSH , but couldn't manage to make it work. How can I log into my first account ? What to do ?

Comment: This is how I resolved the issue for MacOS: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71520433/4685823).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your username (note: *not* your email address) in the SSH line:

`ssh workaccountname@bitbucket.org recovery_codes`

As long as your SSH agent has the correct key loaded, this will connect as the `workaccountname` user. (You can also force it to use the correct key with `-i /path/to/key`.)