# Problem adding SSH key for one of my multiple bitbucket accounts

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

I have a problem with my Bitbucket multiple accounts.

This is my current situation:

- MacOS Catalina 10.15.5
- My ~/.ssh folder has this:

> ```
> -rw-------+   1 myuser  mygroup   1679 12 oct  2016 id_rsa
> -rw-r--r--@   1 myuser  mygroup    411 12 oct  2016 id_rsa.pub
> -rw-------+   1 myuser  mygroup   1823 25 feb 13:50 mycompany
> -rw-r--r--@   1 myuser  mygroup    394 25 feb 13:50 mycompany.pub
> ```

- I have a Bitbucket company account whose SSH key is the same as mycompany.pub
- I have a Bitbucket personal account whose SSH Key is the same as id_rsa.pub

Whenever I do anything related with my Bitbucket personal account (git clone, push...) everything works fine.

On the other hand, to do things with my Bitbucket company account I have to add my username to the commands, for example:

```
git clone https://mycompany@bitbucket.org/blablabla
```

If I don't add my username I get permission errors.
This is a big problem using scripts that I cannot modify (for example with "pod lib lint" and things that access bitbucket private repositories of my company).

What I've tried so far:

- Checking if my ssh-agent is running:

> ```
> $ eval `ssh-agent -s`
> Agent pid 5788
> ```

- Checking my ssh-agent shows this:

> ```
> $ ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -l'
> Identity added: /path/to/my/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/path/to/my/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
> 2048 SHA256:... /path/to/my/user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
> ```

- Since I see my ssh-agent doesn't include my company key I add it:

> ```
> $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/mycompany
> Identity added: /path/to/my/user/.ssh/mycompany (mycompany)
> ```

- But if I check my ssh-agent again, the key has not been included:

> ```
> $ ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -l'
> Identity added: /path/to/my/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/path/to/my/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
> 2048 SHA256:... /path/to/my/user/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
> ```

I've tried too changing my ~/.ssh config file from this:

> ```
> Host *
>   UseKeychain yes
> ```

To this:

> ```
> Host *
>   AddKeysToAgent yes
>   UseKeychain yes
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> Host mycompanybitbucket
>   Hostname bitbucket.org
>   User mycompany
>   AddKeysToAgent yes
>   UseKeychain yes
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mycompany
> ```

Restarted the shell and trying all again, with the same results: I have no permissions to access my company bitbucket repos.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I've tried another thing that make things more confusing.

If I overwrite id_rsa and id_rsa.pub with mycompany and mycompany.pub and run this:

> ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -l'

The output is this:

> ```
> Identity added: /path/to/my/user/.ssh/id_rsa (mycompany)
> 2048 SHA256:... mycompany (RSA)
> ```

This made me thing that the certificate was this time the correct one and everything should work well. But not, after this, all git commands keep returning permission error.

Comment: This is how I resolved the issue for MacOS: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71520433/4685823).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out. My problem was with all access to https://bitbucket.org, they needed to include the username but in some places I wasn't able to edit these URLs.

So I was studying how to add a default username to these URLs and it worked.
Just running these 2 commands fixed my problem:

> ```
> $ git config --global credential.helper cache
> $ git config --global credential.https://bitbucket.org.username mycompany
> ```