# After the upgrade to TortoiseGit v1.8.15.0 and Git v2.5.0 hosts cannot be found

Tags: ssh, tortoisegit, plink

I've just updated my TortoiseGit from `v1.7.*` to `v1.8.15.0` and Git from `1.*`  to `v2.5.0.windows.1`. Now trying to perform a remote operation like `pull` I'm getting errors:

> git.exe pull -v --progress "origin"
>
> Unable to open connection: Host does not existfatal: Could not read
>   from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.
>
> git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (1747 ms @ 19.08.2015 18:43:33)

I changed the `SSH client` setting from `TortoiseGitPlink` to `PuTTY`. It didn't work as well, but the `PuTTY Error` provided following information:

> Unuble to open connection to github.com-foo
>
> Host does not exist

I work with aliases and my `~/.ssh/config` looks like this:

```
#github.com-foo account
Host github.com-foo
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_foo

#github.com-bar account
Host github.com-bar
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_bar
```

That worked before the upgrade and is still working in `msys`.

TortoiseGit seems to ignore the `config`. How to make TortoiseGit respect the `config` again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PuTTY and TortoiseGitPlink do not respect `.ssh/config` (as described in e.g. [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3225862/3906760) or https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996). Both tools store, like Windows tools, their configuration in registry.

For using PuTTY in your scenario, please see the [TortoiseGit Manual - Tips and tricks for SSH/PuTTY](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html).

PS: `.ssh/config` is the config file for OpenSSH. If you want to use OpenSSH, set the ssh client to `ssh.exe` in TortoiseGit network settings (there is no need to use the full path to `ssh.exe` as it is on the `%PATH%`):

[image]