# TortoiseGit authentication fails if i clone

Tags: bitbucket, dreamweaver, git-bash, tortoisegit

Can anyone help me out here. I have a problem with authentication if i clone. I can clone via the terminal (Git Bash for windows), but it fails if i want to clone in the windows folder.
I have contacted Bitbucket but it seems that the problem is with TortoiseGit for the authentication.

I use openssh with Git Bash for windows.
Error message when i try to clone is:
TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

I have tried to clone via the Git-Bash with following command: git clone --progress -v "git@bitbucket.org:D-P/test.git" "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Users\Git\test" and that is working.

I have search for several forums about that problem but i couldn't find the right solution for my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using https or ssh (openssh or putty)?

Comment: ssh - openssh delivered with Git

Comment: Why you giving me -2

Comment: Yor question does not show any research efford and also does not contain any information in order to assess it.

Comment: I have updated my post. Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: See https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#sshconfigignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseGit uses TortoiseGitPlink by default as SSH client. As you told me in the comments, you are using OpenSSH on git cli, you also have to tell TortoiseGit to use OpenSSH (also see https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#sshconfigignored and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115724/3906760).

Go to TortoiseGit settings -> Network and put `ssh.exe` as ssh client (there is no need to use the full path to `ssh.exe` as it is on the `%PATH%`):

[image]