# How to configure TortoiseGit to work with remote repo?

Tags: git, ssh, tortoisegit

Ever since reinstalling my office machine I have a problem with using TortoiseGit to access (and particularly push) to our remote server.

In my company the central repo is maintained on a remote server. On my Windows 10 PC I have Cygwin, Git and TortoiseGit installed. I also have access to a remote Linux account.

A while back I generated my public and private SSH keys and used them since then. I regularly use the Cygwin terminal (bash) to access the remote repo, and usually use TortoiseGit to manage the commits and examine logs. In the past I was able to use TortoiseGit for accessing the remote repo as well but now I cannot make it to work.

When I configure the client's **Git/Remote** pane to use the HTTP URL I can clone a repo. When I use the GIT URL I am asked to provide the password to the remote server. I cannot push with neither URLs.

[image]

I am using the `id_rsa.pub` key from Cygwin's `home/.ssh` directory in the **Putty Key** field (tried also the private key `id_rsa`). Also, in the **Network** pane I set the SSH client to `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe`.

So, since my bash flow works just fine, I assume something is wrong with my TortoiseGit settings. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing several things here: Git for Windows, Cygwin and OpenSSH and PuTTY.

1. You have an OpenSSH key, so you can't use PuTTY with TortoiseGit or enter a OpenSSH key in the `PuTTY key`-field. (You already seem to have configured ssh.exe, so that's fine - or you have to convert your OpenSSH key to a PuTTY key, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115724/3906760 in order to use TortoiseGitPLink).
2. You seem to have Git for Windows installed as you have selected the shipped `ssh.exe` from that package. This might cause an incompatibility. Just select `ssh.exe` for the ssh client to make sure the `ssh.exe` from the corresponding git installation is used.
3. It is unclear to me which `git.exe` is used in TortoiseGit, I assume Git for Windows is used as this is recommended for TortoiseGit. Here, I assume the problem you face is that Git for Windows uses a different `%HOME%` compared to your Cygwin environment. To fix this either copy your `.ssh` folder to your Windows home directory or explicitly define `%HOM%E` to point to your Cygwin home.

Btw. Cygwin Git is not recommended as it is broken - it does not pass all the Git tests of the Git testsuite (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32427897/3906760).

TLDR: Use `ssh.exe`as SSH client, make sure the correct `git.exe` is used and that your `.ssh`-folder is in the correct `%HOME%`.