# How to use gitolite and TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit, gitolite, plink

I use local git repos.
It is located on an Ubuntu machine,
and, I installed gitolite in local git.

I succeed git clone in linux client.
but I failed windows client.
I want to use TortoiseGit client in windows.

I tried,

1. create .PPK file using PuttyGen.exe
2. upload keydir in gitolite-admin repo
3. git clone in windows

let's see follows, plz

[image]

but result is

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why It need to git-repo's password? I uploaded .ppk file correctly.
and, I don't understand this message,  "does not appear to be a git repository"
repository located exactly. /home/git-repo/repositories/test.git

I want to use TortoiseGit with gitolite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not upload the ppk file to gitolite, (1) it also includes your private key and (2) openssh cannot read it (you need to open it with Puttygen and copy the public key string to a file which you upload to gitolite).

An alternative would be to use OpenSSH with TortoiseGit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115724/3906760