# GitHub and using SSH keys

Tags: github, ssh, tortoisegit

I know there are lots of links about this topic and some official ones. I have tried several SO answers too but I am still at a loss.

- I have created a ED25519 SSH private key (PPK file) and public key (PUB file).
- My key has a passphrase.
- I have added my public key to GitHub.
- I have added my PPK key to Putty Pageant.
- I have changed the repository to use the SSH key URL as identified on GitHub.

But it will not push and came up with a port 22 issue. After research I found and answer that said to create a `config` file and put this in it:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

then, I tried this command:

`ssh -vT git@github.com`

It found my key and asked for the passphrase. It worked, although it does say this:

```
Hi xxxxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2160, received 2304 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9143.6, received 9753.2
debug1: Exit status 1
```

It has that comment about the shell? Anyway, I then go into TortoiseGit Git settings and confirm it is using my "noreply" email address, has the SSH git URL and that I have selected the PPK PuttyLink file.

Despite all of this, I can't push to the remote server. Tried for 3 days. :(

What step am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration file `.ssh/config` is not honored by PuTTY. [Switch to OpenSSH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32115724/3906760) or [configure a session in PuTTY](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-ssh-howto.html) or use the url `ssh://git@ssh.github.com:443/...`.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/support/faq/#howsshdifferentport

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way in TortoiseGit to verify that the connection is now OK without me faking a commit to push?

Comment: Note that I already mentioned I am using pageant, so I thought that that side of things was set up.

Comment: Do a clone or fetch

Comment: I tried a push (with the ssh URL) and it came up with a popup window about not trustiung the certificate. I accedpted with Yes. But then it came up with a plink "login" window and I have tried my email address, noreply address and github username. Does not accept.

Comment: It says "no supported authentication methods available (server sentL publickey)

Comment: If I set it to use ssh as per linked answer, and use the url you suggested it still does not push. It says: ajtru@ssh.github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: The username is missing: `ssh://git@ssh....`

Comment: managed to get it to work! Trying another repository to confirm

Comment: It worked again on the other repository. I set it to ssh.exe and just the regulat git url and it pushes. Although, for both repositories it did prompt the passphrase request for some reason.

Comment: OpenSSH does not use PuTTYAgent

Comment: Ah, OK. So I just have to type every time I need to push.

Comment: This also helped: https://interworks.com/blog/2021/09/15/setting-up-ssh-agent-in-windows-for-passwordless-git-authentication/