# GitHub multiple accounts: Can authenticate SSH with both accounts, but cannot clone repositories of one

Tags: authentication, github, ssh

I'm on my work computer, which is already [successfully] configured to connect to our GitHub account and authenticate our commits using SSH and GPG keys, respectively. Before I began changing things, my **original** `~/.ssh/config` file was this:

```
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

To add my personal account, I generated a new SSH key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal`), added the `.pub` part to my personal GitHub account, and **modified** my `~/.ssh/config` file to the following:

```
# Default
Host *
 AddKeysToAgent yes
 UseKeychain yes

# Personal
Host github.com-PERSONAL
 HostName github.com
 User git
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal

# Work
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

After this change, I am still able to interact with my work account without a problem – nothing has changed. However, when I attempt to interact with my personal account using

```
git clone git@github-PERSONAL:nikblanchet/myrepository.git
```

, I am getting an error message:

```
Cloning into 'myrepository'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-personal: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

To narrow down the issue, I decided to try a simple SSH authentication

```
ssh -T git@github.com-PERSONAL
```

, and, surprisingly, it worked!

```
Hi nikblanchet! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

(Running `ssh -T git@github.com` authenticated with my work account, as expected.)

So now I'm lost. Why can `ssh -T` resolve the hostname while `git clone` cannot? What did I miss?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config  See ssh-add  - also, try exiting your shelling, opening a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You URL should be:

```
github.com-PERSONAL:nikblanchet/myrepository.git
```

You tried first

```
git@github-PERSONAL:nikblanchet/myrepository.git
```

That is why it was not able to resolve `github-PERSONAL`, which is *not* in your config file.
`github.com-PERSONAL` is.

Note: no need to add the `git@` part: your config file does specify the `User git` already.