# Git clone, push and pull from multiple users on Ubuntu server

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, ssh-keys, linode

### Background

I have a `Linode` server with `Ubuntu 16.04` as on OS on it. The server is for my internal team. We have repos hosted on github, bitbucket and gitlab. Only server admin has the access to the server.

We have generated `ssh keys` for all the users, added them to git providers and cloned the repos

### Problem Statement

Whenever I do git pull on server, it always asks for the main passphrase of main key file

```
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

When I enter the passphrase, it shows me `Permission denied error`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That simply means the public key for that (passphrase-protected) private key is not registered on the remote hosting service side (GitHub or BitBucket or GitLab)

See "[Testing your SSH connection](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)"

See also "[Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17158985/6309)" to manage multiple identities.