# How to configure multiple github accounts on your computer?

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-enterprise

So, I have my work computer and that is connected to my GitHub Enterprise Account (`github.company.com`) on the terminal. Now I want to set up my personal account (`github.com`) on here too.

I've been following this tutorial - https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574
and on step 3 when I have to create my config file should my `HostName` be `github.company.com` or `github.com`? Can I have any (meaningful) name for `Host`? Also, what does `User` here mean?

Also, how do I switch between both these accounts on the terminal - i.e. my personal and my enterprise account? There are certain things I need to commit from my personal account, and use the enterprise account with the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48241261/7976758

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Detailed steps to use two GitHub accounts on the same PC as below:

#### 1. Create SSH key for the github.company.com account

If you already added the SSH key to your github.company.com account, then skip this step.

First, use `ssh-keygen` to create `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in `C:\Users\username\.ssh`.

Then, add the content of `id_rsa.pub file` as a SSH key in github.company.com account.

#### 2. Create SSH Key for your personal account github.com

Use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email address for the personal github account"`, and save the key in `/c/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa_personal`.

Now add the content of `id_rsa_personal.pub` file as a SSH Key in your personal GitHub account.

#### 3. Config the two SSH Keys

In `C:\Users\username\.ssh` diectory, create a `config` file with below content:

```
Host github.company.com
  HostName github.company.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host github-personal
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

#### 4. Work with the two GitHub accounts by SSH protocol

You can clone your github.company.com account by:

```
git clone git@github.company.com:companyaccountname/reponame
```

And then add the personal account as a remote in the local repo by:

```
git remote add personal git@github-personal:personalaccountname/reponame
```

To get the file from personal account to company repo by below commands:

```
git merge upstream master --allow-unrelated-histories
# make changes
git add .
git commit -m 'add the changes from peronal repo'
git push origin master
```

---

To commit/push changes from local company repo by the committer of the personal repo, you just need to re-config the username and email before committing changes in the local repo:

```
git config user.name <personal github account username>
git config user.email <email for login the personal github account>
```

When you want to commit changes with the company account, just re-config username and email again before committing changes.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a ton for your response! I've successfully completed up till step 3! I cloned a repo to local from my company account but I wish to push my changes using my personal account - how do I go about that?

Comment: I added it in the last part of my answer, you can have a try.

Comment: This is the perfect answer! Thanks a ton! Worked like a charm!