# I don't have ~/.ssh/config file but multiple GitHub accounts works, how?

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys

I'm trying to configure another GitHub account to be able work from my machine. I started to looking around and I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17158985/2401535):

> Set up multiple ssh profiles by creating/modifying ~/.ssh/config. Note the slightly differing 'Host' values:

So as I (already) have multiple accounts working (I don't remember how and when I did that) I wanted to just add another entry in `~/.ssh/config`. But it appears that I don't have such file. Maybe it is located somewhere else? Or maybe my machine is configured in some other way? Where to start searching?

Answer (score 10):

This is behavior of *ssh* rather than git.

In your `~/.ssh` folder you have your private key. The name of the file for your private key is `id_rsa` by default. When ever your ssh client  has to login to a ssh server it reads the key from that file.

But in some cases you may want to use a different private key for authentication. In that case you create the file `~/.ssh/config` and you add a section with an alias (the host name you write at the command line) the real host name and the path to he alternative key file on your local system:

```
# ~/.ssh/config
Host alternative-github
    HostName github.com
    User MyOtherGithubUser
    IdentityFile /media/me/MyUsbThumbDrive/.ssh/MyOtherGithubUsers-id_rsa
```

Whit this configuration *ssh* looks on my UBS thumb drive for the private key when  I clone the repo like this:

```
git clone git@alternative-github:/MyOtherGithubUser/someRepositoty.git
```

#### conclusion

As long as you use the same public/private key pair with your git projects and the private key is available as `~/.ssh/id_rsa` you don't need the file `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: *"But in some cases you may want to use a different private key for authentication... as long as you use the same public/private key pair with your git projects..."* It seems like you're advocating here for using the same public/private key for multiple services, which definitely doesn't seem like good practice.

Comment: @HashimAziz *"It seems like you're advocating here for using the same public/private key for multiple services"* **--** No, I don't! I'm just answering the OPs question.

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to just add another entry in `~/.ssh/config`

You can create it, but:

- you need to have generate public/private keys with a different name

  ```
  ssh-keygen -q -P "" -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/key2
  ```
- you need to have registered `~/.ssh/key2.pub` on your remote server second account
- you need to have a config file with:

  ```
  Host github2
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/key2
  ```

Note the User here: '`git`', *not* '`another GitHub account`'

- you need to change the origin remote URL to use that entry:

  ```
  git remote set-url origin github2:MySecondAccount/MyRepo.git
  ```