# Git - per-remote credentials (SSH key)

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a Git repository that gets pushed to different remotes.

```
cd soCoolItHasToBeDuplicated;

git remote add foo git@github.com/...
git push foo;
git remote add bar git@github.com/...
git push bar;
```

Now, the repo has some SSH key configured.
But GitHub prevents the same SSH key to be reused for other user.
So I need to use other SSH key for the other repo.

[There is the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` var](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use) to use different SSH key. But I would like this to work transparently, without additional variable or script.

**Basically what I am looking for is something like:**

```
git remote set-key foo ~/.ssh/id_rsa-github-foo
```

Is there something such?
(I know GitHub specifically has organizations and stuff. I want a vanilla `git` solution.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config)

Comment: *"But GitHub prevents the same SSH key to be reused for other user."* but github supports  [deploy-keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys) that you can share with other users.