# Using multiple Github accounts with SSH keys

Tags: git, powershell, github, ssh

I have recently been given access to a Github repository that I'll call `work` for this question, access to this repository has been given to my via SSH keys.

I use SSH keys for my account (that I'll call `me`) which hasn't given me a problem and continues to act normally for any repository that is under this account.

I have my `config` file set up like this

```
Host me.github.com
      HostName github.com
      User git
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/me

Host work.github.com
     HostName github.com
     User git
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/work
```

When I try to use `ssh-add -l` both keys show up, and both accounts have the correct public key added to them.

Sending the command `ssh -T git@github.com` returns `Hi me! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`, although if I send the command `ssh -T git@work.github.com` it responds in the correct way.

Both origins for fetch and push are set to the ssh link as verified by `git remote -v`

I have tried [following this gist](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996), [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@trionkidnapper/ssh-keys-with-multiple-github-accounts-c67db56f191e), [and this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config), along with a few others with no success.

I should probably also include that I'm running on Windows 10 LTSB build 14393, Powershell 5.1, git version 2.19.1.windows.1, and posh-git 0.7.3.1 installed through Chocolatey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check your two SSH keys with:

```
ssh -Tv me.github.com
ssh -Tv work.github.com
```

Second, you can add for testing in a repo both URLs:

```
git remote set-url origin me.github.com:<auser>/<arepo>
git remote origin originWork work.github.com:<auser>/<arepo>
```

(no need for `git@` in the URL)

From there, you can use one or the other origin to pull/push.