# Git multiple git account with the same host

Tags: git, github

because of some reason, l have two github account now. l know how to set two account under two git host, but how to set two or more account with one git host

assume now l have this two account `a@gmail.com`, `b@gmail.com`

and these are all belong to github, so, what am l need to do?

Comment: Have you tried? https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+multiple+accounts