# Git includeIf for personal and work profiles doesn't work

Tags: git, include, config, profile

I've been googling about this, trying different methods from different sources... but it doesn't work.

I want to push commits with my personal profile (defined with "git config --global user.email ...") unless I'm on my work folder.

The content of my .gitconfig is located at C:/Users/my-user/

```
[user]
    name = Personal
    email = personal@personal.com

[includeIf "gitdir: F:/Work/CompanyName/"]
    path = F:/Work/CompanyName/.gitconfig-work
```

Content of my .gitconfig-work is located at F:/Work/CompanyName/

```
[user]
    name = Work
    email = work@work.com
```

When I go to a cloned repository from work located at:

`F:/Work/CompanyName/Project`

I use:

`git config --show-origin --get user.email`

And it shows:

`file:C:/Users/<my-user>/.gitconfig`

Instead of the route I defined to work.

Thanks for your help.

## ✨ For the future googlers

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Icaruk/f024a18093dc28ec1588cfb90efc32f7) explaining the steps.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to remove one space in:

```
[includeIf "gitdir: F:/Work/CompanyName/"]
```

i.e., make this read:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:F:/Work/CompanyName/"]
```

Note the lack of a blank between the colon after `gitdir` and the path name to be tested.

(Your Git also needs to be at least version 2.13.  You might consider using `gitdir/i:f:/work/companyname/` so that you are not case-sensitive here, assuming your host system is also not case-sensitive, as the `F:` part suggests.  [The final slash is important as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61543355/git-includeif-for-personal-and-work-profiles-doesnt-work/61544074?noredirect=1#comment128979221_61544074); don't omit it without understanding what it does)

Comment: The last tutorial site I visited had space after gitdir, I thougth It was not important.
Thanks :)

Comment: When I cloned already the repo with a tool(sourcetree), and check the email, it worked. But, when I want to clone a repo from company, `git config user.email` shows my personal email and I can not access to company repo.

Comment: @Dr.jacky: when you run `git clone`, you are in effect running a series of separate Git commands, starting with `mkdir` and `git init`, then `git remote add`, then `git fetch`, and so on. There might be some bug(s) in the code that combines all of this into one process, that forgets to include something here. If you can set up a reproducer you can send a bug report to the Git folks.

Comment: Note, however, that `user.email` is *not* used for *authentication*. Authentication is done entirely outside of Git itself. If you're having trouble accessing a company repository, this is usually due to an authentication setting.

Comment: @torek Even after following this successfully: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17158985/421467, I can not clone a new repo under an empty folder, under CompanyFolder. I sent an email to the mailing list.

Comment: My issue was that Ubuntu's default Git version was 2.11 instead of 2.13+.

Comment: I'm working on macOS, and it turns out you need to end your path with trailing `/`, in my case instead of `[includeIf "gitdir:~/Work"]` I had to do `[includeIf "gitdir:~/Work/"]`

Comment: @Forsaken: all the examples end with a slash. The documentation states that when you use a `pattern [that] ends with /, ** will be automatically added` (see [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) and search for the gitdir directive in includeIf directives), so if you want to match things *under* ~/Work you will need either the trailing slash (to get Git to add `**`) or `/**`. But to match one *particular* repository in ~/Work you could spell it out.

Comment: @torek I probably didn't noticed that or thought it was ambiguous. Thanks for explanation how git treats trailing `/`!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Forsaken as it is a detail easy to miss