# How to automatically change my local git config `user.email` depending on the git repository origin I'm cloning from?

Tags: git

I'm working with mainly two types of repositories on my laptop, on one hand, the ones for my projects at work, and the other the ones for oss projects, but they use different `user.email` in `git config --list` (same `user.name` tho).

I'm wondering if there is a way to properly set the `user.email` (the one local to the repository) right from the start when I'm cloning a new project, (knowing that the global config is set to my oss projects).

The reason is that every now and then I forget to manually set the local configuration of my work projects and end up pushing commits signed with the wrong user (ie. the oss one) and then I had to rebase the last N commits or so, which can be quite annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git itself does not have a way to do precisely what you've asked for.  There are two obvious approaches to getting the same *result*, though.

- One uses a feature that was new in Git version 2.13, called `includeIf`.  Here, you would use the *location within your collection of repositories* to determine how to configure items.  For details, see [Git includeIf for personal and work profiles doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61543355/1256452).
- The other is to stop using `git clone` to make clones.  Instead, write your own command, that consists of running `git clone`, then running `git config`.  For referring to this here, I'll call it `git clone-and-config` though you would probably want a short name like `git cc`.

  This command can be a Git *alias* that uses the `!` syntax to run multiple commands, or a script named `git-clone-and-config` that Git can find so that `git clone-and-config` runs your `git-clone-and-config` script.  Of course if you are going to write your own script, you can just call it whatever you want, and invoke it without the `git` prefix.  The only reason to use the `git` prefix is to make it feel like it's "part of Git", even though you wrote it yourself.

  For details about this alternative, see [How to embed bash script directly inside a git alias](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1309430/1256452).

One last note: `git clone` can set configuration values in the new clone, at `git clone` time.  So you can simplify the last part to:

```
git clone -c 'user.email=A U Thor <thor@example.com>' <url>
```

which means you can make it a non-`!` style Git alias:

```
[alias]
    cloneasfred = git clone -c 'user.email=Fred Flintstone <fflint@bedrock.prehisory>'
    cloneasbarney = git clone -c 'user.email=Barney Rubble <brub@bedrock.prehistory>'
```

Be careful!  `git -c user.email=... clone` *does not* do the right thing, while `git clone -c user.email=...` does.  The position of the `-c` is crucial here.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is really thorough.