# Multiple Github username and email on same device?

Tags: git, ssh

I have a personal github account and then another for work. My Directory structure:

```
~/Projects/work
~/Projects/personal
```

Within each of those directories are various repos corresponding to work or personal projects.

My work Github has a separate username and email than my personal one.

I followed [this guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/) to create two separate ssh keys. I got as far as step 4:

1. Step1: Generated two ssh keys. A default one and then one where I passed my work username and pw e.g. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@work_mail.com" -f "id_rsa_work_user1"`
2. Added the corresponding keys to the relevant github accounts in gh settings.
3. Registered the new keys: `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work_user1`
4. Set up an ssh config file per the example

<[I have to add this here or my code block below won't format after a numbered list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298640/how-do-i-format-as-code-after-a-list)/>

```
# Personal account, - the default config
Host github.com
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   
# Work account-1
Host github.com-work_user1    
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work_user1
```

In the terminal, in any directory, whether home or in one of the paths above, work or personal projects, I get my personal Github details witht he following commands:

```
git config user.name
git config user.email
```

If I try to push to a work repo I get a permission denied error. I could, I guess, overwrite each time with e.g. git config user.name "User 1", my work username and then the same for my email. But that seems prone to accident and me forgetting which one is currently set when pushing projects.

What's the 'right' way to handle multiple GH accounts on the same device. Ideally I'd have them set at the repo or directory level. E.g. any repos in `~/Projects/work` should use my work gh settings while any in `~/Projects/personal` should use my personal settings.

What's the recommended solution? How can I set this up?

Comment: Either have two different users on the computer (you can local-ssh to the other user when you work with it) or set the `user.name` and `user.email` per repo by not giving the `--global` parameter when setting it.

Comment: @fredrik could you expand on your second option? Perhaps as an answer? How could I do that, set user name and email at the repo level? When you say 'by not setting the global paramter, I don't know where to write or not write that? Is there a way to make this permanent per repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

You'll probably want to use both `includeIf` *and* carefully-adjusted URLs.

To see how this works (plus various Git version caveats), read through the long section.

## Long

We need to separate things into two parts here.  First, let's *describe it:* what program uses what, when, and how.  Then let's *worry about how to use these conveniently*.

- There's the stuff *Git* uses when you run `git commit`.  This is what `user.name` and `user.email` are for.<sup>1</sup>
- Then, independent of any of that, there's the stuff that *ssh* uses when you run `git fetch` or `git push` with an `ssh://git@github.com/path/to/repo.git` or `git@github.com:path/to/repo.git` URL.<sup>2</sup>

You configure *Git* settings with `git config`.  You configure *ssh* settings by editing files in `$HOME/.ssh/`, or wherever your system's ssh, or the auxiliary ssh, puts them.<sup>3</sup>

Let's now dive into the ssh part.

---

<sup>1</sup>Whenever you make a *new* commit with Git, Git needs to know several things to put into the new commit:

- Your name, e.g., "A. U. Thor".
- Your email address, e.g., `thor@example.com`.
- The current date-and-time.
- A log message.
- A snapshot: the exact contents for every file, to put into the new commit.

Git finds the date-and-time on its own, using your computer's clock.  Use whatever software is appropriate to keep your computer's clock correct to make this work right.

Git gets the log message from you.  Use whatever you like to provide the right log message.

Git gets the snapshot from whatever is in Git's index.  Use `git add` to adjust Git's index, so that you have the correct snapshot.  (This is why you have to `git add` files all the time, even if they're not *new* files: it's not that Git isn't going to put them in the commit, it's that Git will put the *old version* in the file, because when Git checked out a commit earlier, that's the version it got *out* of the commit, and put in Git's index.  The `git add` command has Git update its index copy of the file.)

The `user.name` and `user.email` settings are just for these items: author/committer name, and author/committer email address.  You can put *anything you want* here; Git does not know or care who you are, and does not verify these.  (Other software may, eventually, try to figure out who you are, and might care, so it's generally just a loss to you if you fake these, but Git itself won't care.)

<sup>2</sup>I've written these as `git@github.com` but you can use just `github.com`, or something even shorter, depending on how you configure *ssh itself*.  See the section on ssh below.  The `github.com:path` spelling is shorter and has the same effect as `ssh://github.com/path`, but I prefer the explicit `ssh://` myself.  They really do mean the same thing to Git—not to ssh, but Git strips this part off before *invoking* ssh—so you can use whichever you prefer here.

<sup>3</sup>On systems that come with a working [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell_Protocol), Git generally just *uses the system's ssh*.  On Windows, however, a lot of older Windows systems have either a defective ssh, or no ssh at all, so a lot of Git-for-Windows installations come with a private ssh implementation as well.  You must find out which ssh your system uses, if you are in this situation, and see where to configure it.  You may be able to configure your Git to use the system ssh; if you have a modern Windows system, this may be a good idea.  I don't use Windows and hence don't have all the details here.

---

#### How ssh works, in a nutshell

While ssh has lots of little side jobs to perform, its one big thing is to *establish a secure communications stream*.  To do this, ssh needs to *authenticate*.  For our purposes here, we'll skip over all but the simple public/private-key authentication method, and in particular how *GitHub* will decide who you are.  This lets us ignore a lot of irrelevant-to-us details.  (They do matter if you're using ssh more generally, but not if you're fetching from, and pushing to, GitHub.)

What ssh will do is:

- look up a host name to find an IP address, or take an IP address directly;
- connect to a server *at* that IP address, at some numeric *port* (default 22, which is the standard ssh port);
- collect a "fingerprint" from the server there, and see if it matches the known fingerprint from the last connection;<sup>4</sup>
- if all looks good, send enough information for the other end to figure out who you are: they'll send a challenge, your ssh will send a response, and at the end of all of this, they will have your *public key* and be reasonably certain that *you* have the corresponding *private key*.

In the end, then, they figure out who you are from your *public key*.  They don't believe you *just because you have this key:* the **public** key is, after all, available to the public.  But this particular public key is *paired with* a **private** key, which you *don't* give out to anyone else.  They send a challenge, using your public key that you've already sent to them, and you—or your ssh—answer back, using your private key, and the fact that you *can* respond indicates that you hold the right private key.

What all this boils down to is:

- You must give GitHub your public key, using their web interface.  This is how they will decide that you are *you*.  If you want to be two people, "you-at-home" and "you-at-work", you need to give them *two* public keys.
- Later, when you come in to access some particular repository, you must give GitHub *the right public key*.  You don't give them just *any* public key: if you want access to "you-at-work" repositories, you have to give them the you-at-work public key (only!).

So: how do we do that?  If you have *two* (or more) public keys, how do we make sure that ssh hands, to GitHub, one *particular* key?  **This is where the `.ssh/config` entries come in.**  Let's look at this one:

> ```
> # Work account-1
> Host github.com-work_user1    
>    HostName github.com
>    User git
>    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_work_user1
> ```

The line `Host github.com-work_user1` means that ssh will use this information when you run:

```
ssh [user@]github.com-work_user1
```

or equivalent.  This means that the *URL* we have *Git* use must resemble `ssh://github.com-work_user1/path/to/repo.git`, not `ssh://github.com/path/to/repo.git`.

(I personally recommend taking away the `.com` part here: make this `Host gh-work` for instance, or maybe `Host ghwork.short` or similar, to make it visually distinctive.  The ssh command will match on this first, before trying to look up any host name to get an IP address.)

The `HostName` part after this is how ssh will look up the IP address, so here we have `github.com` so that ssh won't use the fake name that triggers matching this entry.

The `User git` part lets you omit the `git@` part: instead of `ssh git@gh-work` or whatever, you can just `ssh gh-work`.  Note that if you put in a user name—e.g., `ssh error@gh-work`—things won't work right here: the supplied user in the command itself overrides the `User` line in the config.

The last line shown here, `IdentityFile`, is where things get tricky.  It's *meant* to say: Use the given file (containing the `.pub` public-key) as the public key.  I'll come back to the trickiness in a bit.

There's a *missing additional line* that I recommend:

```
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

This line is not always required, but it means *don't use additional public keys*.  The way I like to think about this is a simple analogy:<sup>5</sup> if someone came to your front door and tried one key, and it didn't work, and they left, you'd probably think: Oh, they went to the wrong house.  If someone comes to your front door and tries a million keys, one at a time, you might just get a bit suspicious.   The `IdentitiesOnly` line means *just try the specific keys I list in this particular entry, not any other keys you might find on some key-ring somewhere*.

Now, you mentioned using `ssh-add`.  This communicates with an *agent*.  What I have found, on various systems, is that when using the agent, you sometimes *must* list the `.pub` file specifically, and when *not* using the agent, you sometimes *must not* list the `.pub` file, of the public/private key-pair.  I'm not going to get into the details here but overall I think this is a bad situation.  If possible, always use the agent and always list the `.pub` file.  It is possible that some systems exist where, even when using the agent, you must leave out the `.pub` here; I don't know of any, but they might exist.  Use `ssh -Tv <github-alias>` to watch ssh offer keys, to see if it is successfully offering the right ones.

If you do use the agent like this, and do not store the private keys on various intermediate hosts, you must `ssh-add` each key that the agent *could* offer based on config, before your ssh can actually use it.  The agent transfers the private key from the source (whichever host that is) to each intermediate host for as long as it needs it.  For more about this, see ssh-specific questions.

---

<sup>4</sup>If it doesn't match, you normally get an alarming message since it looks like someone else is pretending to be the people you previously agreed to talk to.  If you don't have a known fingerprint for this server, ssh will normally ask you to confirm whether to go ahead and remember this fingerprint.  This is all configurable, and to avoid the conversation, you can do an initial connection or use a one-time "scan" (`ssh-keyscan`) as you set things up.  See also [this ServerFault Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/132970/549786).  I don't recommend the `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option in the accepted answer for general use: read the comments and the other answers.  For very specific cases, where you control everything, it's OK, but GitHub isn't one of those specific cases.

<sup>5</sup>Like most analogies, it's OK for a way to think about the problem, but may not stand up to scrutiny.

---

#### How Git uses ssh

For the most part, this is really very simple.  You give Git a URL:

```
git remote add xyzzy https://example.com/path/to/repo1
git remote add plugh ssh://user@example.com/path/to/repo2
```

for instance.  Each URL is stored under a *remote*, in this setup; the remote is the "short name" and otherwise just means the long URL.

When the URL is an *ssh* URL, Git splits it into the `user@host` or `host` part, and the `path/to/repo` part.  Let's use the `plugh` remote as our example here.  Then it runs:

```
ssh user@example.com git-upload-pack path/to/repo2
```

when you run `git fetch plugh`.  The `git-upload-pack` command<sup>6</sup> implements the server side work that lets your client do a `git fetch`.  A similar command, `git-receive-pack`, runs on the server to let your client do a `git push`.

When you connect to GitHub, the *authentication* step they use figures out who you are using the public key you send.  Then they look up the "who you are" that they figured out, and decide whether that "you" has access to the repository given in the upload or receive pack command (and they also make sure that you only use legitimate commands, of course).  **Note that Git has no work to do here; nothing you set *in* Git can affect this.**  All of the work happens in ssh and on the server, and it's all based on the public key you have your ssh send *to* the server.

Again, the way to *test what Git is going to do* is to take Git out of the picture, and run `ssh -Tv host-alias`.  Add more `v` letters to make your particular ssh command even more verbose, to track what it's doing, step by step.  Make sure it's sending the desired public key.  If GitHub have that public key, and if your ssh then passes the challenge/response part, you'll see a message of the form:

```
Hi _____! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
provide shell access.
```

with the blank here filled in with the person they think you are, based on the public key you sent.

---

<sup>6</sup>At some point long ago, this was vaguely intended to be changed to `git upload-pack` instead of `git-upload-pack`.  Recent versions of Git stopped installing `git-foo` for every `git foo` and there was a brief period during which `git-upload-pack` could be removed without being reinstalled, during an upgrade.  If you ever see a problem of this form, it means someone on the server forgot to put the `git-upload-pack` link back and your Git client is still using the old `git-upload-pack` form.  In any case, some clients may now be using `git upload-pack` now.

---

#### Configuring Git, part 1

Now that you have Git connecting *to* GitHub as the right person—or before that point, if you like—it's time to figure out how to get the right name and email address into *new commits you will make*.  That is, we now want to make sure that *Git* gets the right `user.name` and `user.email`.

If you only have one name and email address to use, this is easy: use the `--global` setting.  If you have more than one, well, there are many options here.

Git's configuration system is very flexible, and supports three or more "levels" of configuration (the exact number depends on how you want to count these):

- There's a *system* configuration file.  Often this file simply doesn't exist, i.e., there's no system-wide configurations set.  If it *does* exist, only the system administrator has permission to modify it.  So you wouldn't put your own settings here anyway.
- There is a *per-user* configuration file.  When you log in to your own computer, you're picking a user to use.  Even if your computer has only one user, modern OSes still have "administrator" or "sysadm" or "root" or something as a *concept*, so this distinguishes *you* from "stuff owned by the system".  If your system is designed correctly, this lets you upgrade the system without messing with your own settings and stuff.  Git's per-user configuration file is the `--global` one, and you can edit it directly if you like, with `git config --global --edit`.  Note that this will run your chosen editor—usually from your `core.editor` setting—on that file.  *If you haven't chosen some editor yet, you'll get the system choice or the built-in default.*  One way to fix this is to run `git config --global core.editor name`, for whatever editor you want to use, first.
- Then, there is a *per-repository* configuration.  This has the same format and use as the global configuration, but anything you set for any given repository are only for *that repository*.  Note that `git config --edit`, with no other option, edits this per-repository configuration; `git config user.name Me` sets the setting in the per-repository configuration.
- In modern Git, there is a *per-worktree* configuration.  Use `git config --worktree` to work with this configuration.  This is only used in added work-trees and it's almost always wrong, or at least fishy, to set something here (Git uses this configuration for its own internal purposes).
- You can also use `git config --file *filename` to point `git config` at a particular file.  This is mainly meant for Git's submodule stuff, but can be used for whatever purpose you like.
- If nothing is configured at all for some setting, Git has whatever default it has built in, if any.  For instance, if `core.editor` is not set (and none of the environment variables is set either<sup>7</sup>), Git always has a compiled-in default editor such as `vim` or `nano`.
- Finally, you can override the setting for *one command* using `git -c variable=value`, e.g., `git -c user.name="Scary Spice" -c user.email=melb@virgin-records.com commit`.

The *way this is intended to be used* is straightforward, but not simple: **you can configure each setting in every configuration file, and the "most local" setting will override.**  That is, you could set `user.name` to `Anonymous` in the *system* configuration, `User` in the per-user configuration, and `Me` in one specific repository.  A new commit made *by you*, in *that* repository, will have as its author and committer, `Me <email-address>`, because the per-repository `user.name` is `Me`.  The email address part will come from the `user.email` setting.

For `user.name` and `user.email` specifically, there are some extra complications:

- If they're not set at all, your Git may gripe and quit (not make a new commit).  Or, it may use OS-level facilities to *guess* or *find* your name and/or email address.  Whether and how well it can do this depends on the Git version and on your OS, and several Git versions have a bug here where they can crash while trying to do this guessing.
- Another setting, `user.useConfigOnly`, will *suppress* this guessing, so you can use `git config --global user.useConfigOnly true` to avoid having the guessing happen.

By defeating the guessing, you can make sure that if you forgot to configure them, Git won't make commits with the *wrong* name and email address.  So you might want to do this, depending on how you want to set everything else up.

With this in mind, you have a couple of options:

- You can `git config --global user.useConfigOnly true` and force yourself to configure `user.name` and `user.email` locally for each repository.  Note, however, that this particular feature was new in Git version 2.8; older Git versions will ignore the setting (though they may still force you to configure these, depending on their other defaults).
- Then you just have to remember to `git config` the `user.name` and `user.email` settings in every repository (ugh).
- Or, you can `git config --global` the settings you want to use most of the time, and just have to remember to `git config` the `user.name` and `user.email` settings in each *non-default* repository.  That's still kind of "ugh", but perhaps better.

With Git 2.13, however, there's a perhaps-still-better way.

---

<sup>7</sup>Partly for historical reasons, Git will choose the editor to run based on the *first* of:

- `$GIT_EDITOR`
- `core.editor`
- `$VISUAL`
- `$EDITOR`
- compiled-in default

The `$`-prefixed names here are *environment variables*, which sh/bash style command line interpreters set with simple assignments:

```
$ GIT_EDITOR=emacs git config --global --edit
```

will run `emacs` on the global Git configuration file, for instance.

You can also use:

```
$ git -c core.editor=emacs git config --global --edit
```

which requires a bit more typing, but might be easier to remember: it has no special cases.  (To remember the special cases, see [the `git var` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var).)

---

#### Configuring Git, part 2: using includeIf

Git 2.13 learned a new directive in configuration files, spelled `includeIf` (you can use all-lowercase `includeif`, if you prefer, but the camelCase spelling is a nominal standard here).  The `includeIf` directive can test certain conditions, and an interesting one here is `gitdir`.

Here, `gitdir` stands in for the *full path name* to the repository you're working in.  In your case, you have put each project under some appropriate prefix:

> ```
> ~/Projects/work
> ~/Projects/personal
> ```

This means that if the path to some repository is `~/Projects/work/foo/bar/.git`, this must be a *work project*.  If it's `~/Projects/personal/baz/quux/.git`, it must be a *personal project*.

If you want all *work* projects to use a particular `user.name` and `user.email` configuration, you'll want, e.g.:

```
[includeIf "gitdir:~/Projects/work/"]
    path = ~/.git-work
```

and then you'll want to create a `git config` format file in `~/.git-work` in which those settings are set.  You can use `git config --file ~/.git-work user.name work-name`, for instance, to adjust the work setting, or run `git config --edit --file ~/.git-work` to run your favorite editor on that file.

Likewise, you can add an `includeIf` for personal projects, or you can just set `user.name` and `user.email` *before* doing the `includeIf` part (because for these settings, later values override earlier ones).

Be careful with whitespace here (see [Git includeIf for personal and work profiles doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61543355/1256452) for an example where whitespace broke the intended use).  Be aware, too, that the way the `gitdir:` matching works is a little complicated.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for complete details, but in short, the `gitdir:~/path/` notation "means" *do the include if the `.git` directory has a glob match against `~/path/**` after doing tilde expansion*.

#### Conclusion

You'll want to use Git configurations to set `user.name` and `user.email` appropriately for when you make commits.  This has no effect on push and fetch.

You'll want to control the URL for when you run push and fetch, so that Git passes the desired *fake* host name to ssh, so that ssh can supply `github.com` and the correct public key.  I did not mention it above, but Git configuration items of the form `url.base.insteadOf` can be used to *rewrite* the URLs.  You can, in theory, combine this with the `includeIf` trick so that you don't have to fake out the URLs.  I have not tested this myself, and I imagine the debugging could be ... "interesting".