# setting multiple accounts on git and vscode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

So I've recently started to work for a company and I'm trying to set a git environment for both my account, personal and the company. I found a simple solution for it which would be create a config file for multiple ssh keys. My question is, this works perfectly on the terminal, but when I try using vscode it asks me to set

`Make sure you configure your 'user.name' and 'user.email' in git.`

but arent these configurations globally made? is there a way for me to set these for each of my ssh keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a `user.name` and a `user.email` for each repo. Run below command in the git repo where you need to specify the user/email

```
git config user.name <user-name>
git config user.email <user-email>
```

Personnaly, i have a global configuration (i.e. `git config --global user.name` ) for my work (because i have a looooot of projects to deal with), and for my personnal projects (just a few) I do the local configuration like above.

Comment: yeah, that seems to be the only solution :/

Comment: Note that Git provides `includeIf` directives such that you can set `user.name` and `user.email` *conditionally*, based on the *location of the Git directory* in the file system. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61543355/1256452). Whether this works in VSCode (which often doesn't seem to use Git at all, choosing instead to do its own fake Git stuff), I have no idea.