# why .gitconfig [includIf] override the default config

Tags: git

I have two keys to different github account and there is the config `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
        name = example
        email = example@example.com
[pull]
        rebase = true
[rebase]
        autoStash = true
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        process = git-lfs filter-process
        required = true
[includeIf "gitdir/i:/Users/example/Documents/github_2/"]
    [core]
        sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/github2_key"
```

then, I go to a folder that did not at `/Users/example/Documents/github_2/`, and run `git clone github1_private_project`, git told me `Please make sure you have the correct access rights`

It works to git clone the project from account 'github2' in `/Users/example/Documents/github_2/`

---

git version:

```
% git -v
git version 2.39.2 (Apple Git-143)
```

Comment: As per [this doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_example) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61544074/7034621) proper syntax is `gitdir:drive:/some/path`, notice `:` instead of `/` after `gitdir`.

Comment: @orhtej2 [`gitdir/i`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-codegitdiricode) is for case-insensitive comparison. It's not drive `I:`.

Comment: Under `includeIf` there must be a path to an include file. `[core]` terminates `[includeIf]` and starts a new config section which is always (non-conditionally) active.

Comment: @phd Fancy making that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for `includeIf` should be (see [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_includes)):

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:/Users/example/Documents/github_2/"]
path = </path/to/includeFile>
```

The syntax

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:/Users/example/Documents/github_2/"]
    [core]
        sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/github2_key"
```

actually means

```
[includeIf "gitdir/i:/Users/example/Documents/github_2/"]
# No `path` hence no include

[core]
    sshCommand = "ssh -i ~/.ssh/github2_key"
```

where the key `core.sshCommand` is always (unconditionally) defined.

Comment: Ok, it works. looks like I'm looking for the wrong guide :(