# Doing ssh -T git@gitlab.com shows a gitlab user. How do I change this gitlab account?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

There's already another gitlab account being used. So all the git commits are being recorded in this account. How do I change this account?
I tried changing git users the git way. git config --list shows the changed user but still the above gitlab account is being used. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: GitLab (like most other hosted Git services) identifies users by the email address in the commit metadata.  To assign a different author to your commits you have to change this email address.  This can be done using `git config user.email "new@email.address"`.

Comment: This didn't work

Comment: It doesn't retroactively.  This will only apply to new commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using a shared local account, which is not recommended, but everybody does anyway. The Gitlab login is using the ssh key, and the key is linked to a different account.

You can:

- use nominative users instead of a shared account (recommended), each will have its own ssh keys and configuration;
- configure multiple keys and multiple remotes (see [Multiple GitHub Accounts & SSH Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225862/multiple-github-accounts-ssh-config));
- change the SSH keys linked to the current account with your own (if you are the only one currently using that shared account) or unlink that SSH key from the previous user, and link it to your user on Gitlab (this is by far the worse solution);
- use HTTPS instead of SSH (this -by default- will ask for credentials each time you pull/push/etc, allowing more users to use their credentials each time)

Docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Comment: I fhink what the person means is when you click code button the drop down appears where u can pic rhe ssh url or https for the same thing is happening with us it’s mentioned thr git@ user when cloning code it asks for a password

Comment: nope, he's from cli and he mentions git user being changed, but ssh to gitlab still configured as the previous user